# How to use a div id as a php var

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have the following function that pass to the div with `id = "window"`, the value `dbdata` from the database.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function () {
        $('#window').load('crt.php');
    )};
)};
```

How can I get the `id` value and use it in the `php` code below?
 without refresh the page?
    `if ($id = $row["dbdata"]) { do something }`

I added the rest of the code:

index.html

```
`<div id = "window"></div>`

`if ($id = $row["dbdata"]) {do something}`

`<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            setInterval(function () {
                $('#window').load('crt.php')
            }, 3000);
        });
    </script>`
```

crt.php

```
`<?php 
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'user');
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection error: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$result = $conn->query("SELECT id FROM data");
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['dbdata'] . '<br>';
    }
}
?>`
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I added the rest of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simple way could be assign the  GET param in your jquery load url and use it in your php code

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function () {
            $('#window').load('crt.php?id=window')
```

.

```
       if ($_GET['id'] = $row["dbdata"]) { do something }
```

or you instead of load could use ajax get  eg :

```
 $.get( "crt.php?id=window", function( data ) {
      alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
 });
```

in your crt.php

```
if ($_GET['id'] = $row["dbdata"]) { 
   return "hello!";
}
```

Comment: How can I do the same, but without refreshing the page?

Comment: intead of load  ..you could use the ajax  .. take a look  at jquery ajax    http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/   .. you can use this for manage the data retriving iniside cliente page avoding refresh

Comment: answer  updated with a brief sample .hope is clear  ..but you should take a  deep look at ajax tecniques ..in this case jQuery.get()   https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: I added the rest of the code, please can you give me 
the most accurate solution?

Comment: SO .. is not a coding service.. .. is a Question/Answer site.. i think that i have already answer  right to your original question  ..then if you need  more you should post a new question where you explain you new need .. in this case how  avoid the refresh of the page using  the code you are using  . .. this way all the SO communty could help  you, probably in a better way  ..

Answer (score 4):

You can pass values in URL parameters.:

`$('#window').load('crt.php?id=window')`

Then in your php code you can retrieve the parameter using:

`$id = $_GET["id"];`

Comment: How can I do the same, but without refreshing the page?